# Trailing `1` in GolfScript factorial code

Tags: recursion, stack, factorial, golfscript

I'm trying out the first GolfScript code from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/629/92955):

```
4{:n;1:c;{n 1>}{n c*:c;n 1-:n;}while c}:f;f
```

This outputs 241, which has a redudant 1 at the end.
I can't even remove this using `;` at the end of the code.
Is this a bug?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is exactly wrong, but `n` makes a lot of bugs.
So just change the name of variable `n` to something like `i`.